# Understanding pytest fixtures parametrization

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have the following piece of code that works fine:

```py
import pytest

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age=None, height=None, lots_of_properties=None):
        self.name = name
        if age is not None:
            self.age = age
        if height is not None:
            self.height = height
        if lots_of_properties is not None:
            self.lots_of_properties["somepropertykey"] = "somepropertyvalue"

@pytest.fixture
def a_person():
    return Person("simon", 32)

def test_person_name(a_person):
    assert a_person.name == "simon"

def test_person_age(a_person):
    assert a_person.age == 32
```

this is how I have been using fixtures so far. I create a fixture object `a_person` that I can pass to multiple tests. in the above example, I can't really specify the age upon creation, since the `a_person` only defines an age. How can I pass more keywords parameters to the fixture? more over, how can I modify the `a_person` fixture, so that I can also modify the persons name, and age?
I have been googling around and it looks like I have to use `@pytest.mark.parametrize` but I can't seem to understand how it could apply to this case.
basically I would like to have something like:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def a_person(name,age, height, lots_of_properties):
    return Person(name, age, height, lots_of_properties)

# I would like to initialize multiple a_person objects with different params
def test_person_object_1(a_person.name = "alive", a_person.age = 33, a_person.height = 230, a_person.lots_of_properties.{}):
// test stuff
def test_person_object_2(a_person.name = "bob", a_person.age = 18, a_person.height = 180, a_person.lots_of_properties.{}):
// test stuff
```

but I know the last syntax is completely wrong.

Comment: So if the defaults are none you don't set them and let access throw an attribute error down the line?  That's... interesting.  It *might* make sense in an application but it's pretty rare (I've never seen it in the wild)

Answer (score 1):

To do this using `@pytest.mark.parametrize`, all you need is to define the parameters that are expected to be received in the fixture as function parameters and make sure to define them in the `@pytest.mark.parametrize` of the test. Like the parameters `person_name` and `person_age`.

```
import pytest


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age=None, height=None, lots_of_properties=None):
        self.name = name
        if age is not None:
            self.age = age
        if height is not None:
            self.height = height
        if lots_of_properties is not None:
            self.lots_of_properties["somepropertykey"] = "somepropertyvalue"


@pytest.fixture
def a_person(person_name: str, person_age: int) -> Person:
    return Person(person_name, person_age)


@pytest.mark.parametrize("person_name, person_age", [("simon", 32)])
def test_with_parameters(a_person):
    assert a_person.name == "simon"
    assert a_person.age == 32
```

But this simple way is not practical for most cases. As the codebase becomes more complicated, more complicated and direct tests are needed. One of the drawbacks of this way is that all parameters have to be defind for every test even if the test tests only one of the parameters. To overcome this issue, the parameters may be defined as separate fixtures which return a default value. Like the `person_name` and `person_age` fixtures.

```
import pytest


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age=None, height=None, lots_of_properties=None):
        self.name = name
        if age is not None:
            self.age = age
        if height is not None:
            self.height = height
        if lots_of_properties is not None:
            self.lots_of_properties["somepropertykey"] = "somepropertyvalue"


@pytest.fixture
def person_name() -> str:
    return "simon"


@pytest.fixture
def person_age() -> int:
    return 32


@pytest.fixture
def a_person(person_name: str, person_age: int) -> Person:
    return Person(person_name, person_age)


def test_person_name(a_person):
    assert a_person.name == "simon"


def test_person_age(a_person):
    assert a_person.age == 32


@pytest.mark.parametrize("person_name", ["not simon"])
def test_with_parameter_person_name(a_person):
    assert a_person.name == "not simon"


@pytest.mark.parametrize("person_age", [20])
def test_with_parameter_person_age(a_person):
    assert a_person.age == 20


@pytest.mark.parametrize("person_name, person_age", [("person1", 20), ("person2", 22), ("person3", 24)])
def test_with_parameters(a_person):
    if a_person.name == "person1":
        assert a_person.age == 20
    elif a_person.name == "person2":
        assert a_person.age == 22
    elif a_person.name == "person3":
        assert a_person.age == 24
    else:
        assert False, "Incorrect person"
```

This way `test_with_parameter_person_name` can parametrize only the parameter relevant to the test and all other parameters will be the generated from the other fixtures that are not parameterized.

Answer (score 0):

One way to use the pytest mark `@pytest.mark.parametrize` would be something like below.

Also see a link to the docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions

```
import pytest

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age=None, height=None, lots_of_properties=None):
        self.name = name
        if age is not None:
            self.age = age
        if height is not None:
            self.height = height
        if lots_of_properties is not None:
            self.lots_of_properties["somepropertykey"] = "somepropertyvalue"

@pytest.fixture
def a_person():
    return Person("simon", 32)

def test_person_name(a_person):
    assert a_person.name == "simon"

def test_person_age(a_person):
    assert a_person.age == 32

@pytest.mark.parametrize("field", [1,2,3])
def test_parametrize(a_person, field):
    if 'field' == 1:
        assert a_person.name == "simon"
    if 'field' == 2:
        assert a_person.age == 32
    if 'field' == 3:
        assert len(a_person.keys()) > 1

@pytest.mark.parametrize("field", [{1:Person("simon", 31)},{2:Person("simon", 32)},{3:Person("simon", 33)}])
def test_parametrize2(a_person, field):
    if [field.keys()][0] == 1:
        assert a_person.name == "simon"
    if [field.keys()][0] == 2:
        assert a_person.age == 32
    if [field.keys()][0] == 3:
        assert a_person.age == 33
```

Comment: how do you initialize multiple instances of `a_person` with this approach?

Comment: @SimonErnestoCardenasZarate I added another example at the end, see the latest update.